# How to prevent a person from like a post more than once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please bear with me as I'm utterly confused, so my question may seem rather disorganized.

Ok, I have a blog that's created from rails guides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Amongst other tweaks, I added a column for likes for each post on index page. The likes was implemented from this tutorial: http://docs.railsbridge.org/intro-to-rails/hooking_up_votes_and_topics?back=voting_on_topics

So, right now I have four models: User, Article, Comment, and Like.

Right now, the way my likes column works is that when you like it, it increments its number.

However, I'm trying to prevent that happening past one like.

This is the method in ArticlesController

```
def like_vote
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.likes.create
  redirect_to(article_path)
end
```

I'm really confused on how to prevent a person from liking a post more than once.

As it is, right now the only columns in Like model are: `"id", "article_id", "created_at", updated_at", user_id"`

In case anyone wants to know, the column in Article model are: `"id", "title", "text", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id"`

This is how the likes are displayed in Articles view.html.erb

```
<td><%= pluralize(article.likes.count, "like") %></td>
 <td><%= button_to '+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post %></td>
```

And this is the route in the route's file

```
 resources :articles do
    member do
     post '/user/:user_id/like_vote' => 'articles#like_vote'
    end
 end
```

Does this question make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a table to track what users have liked what posts. Then if the user has a like entry for that post you would not allow it. By incrementing the count you don't have record of what user actually liked the post.

Comment: Sigh. That's true. As you've technically answered my question as it is, your answer is accepted. Will create another post regarding on how to make that work.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this gem so you dont have to reinvent the wheel

https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

then you can just do

```
@user.likes @article
```

and to check for the vote

```
@user.voted_up_on? @article # => true
```

Even if you don't use the gem, its worth taking a look at its source as its comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like this

```
def likes_by_user(current_user_id) 
  Like.where('article_id = ? and user_id = ?', self.id, current_user_id).count
end
```

and then use a helper view like this:

```
<% if article.likes_by_user(current_user.id) > 0 %>
<td><%= button_to '+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post, disabled: true %></td>
<% else %> 
<td><%= button_to '+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post %></td>
<%end%>
```

You should also prevent saving in the article controller create method to check the number of likes made by the current user on the particular article.